# Spectrum of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a domain of finite volume in the hyperbolic space $H^n$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-operators, laplacian

What is known about the ($L^2$) spectrum of the minus Laplace-Beltrami operator ($- \Delta$) with zero boundary conditions  on $B =H^n/\Gamma$, where $H^n$ is $n$-dimensional hyperbolic space ($n>1$), $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of the isometry group of $H^n$? Is it possible for the spectrum to be discrete for some $\Gamma$, when $B$ has finite volume but is not (sub)compact? If so,  it could be generalized  for a  large class of (generic) $B$ (with smooth boundary) of finite volume. (When the closure of $B$ is compact the spectrum seems to be discrete.)  Are there universal bounds (from below) on the spectrum of ($- \Delta$) on $B$ of finite volume (with smooth boundary)? The case of special interest is $n=2$ and  $\Gamma = PSL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ - well-known modular group.

Comment: did you check this: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68376/laplace-beltrami-operator-on-surfaces?rq=1

Comment: You should check Chapters XII, XIII and XIV of Serge Lang's book ``$SL_2(\mathbb{R})$'' (where SL doesn't stand for Serge Lang): you will see that, for $\Gamma=SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the spectrum of the Laplace operator has both a continuous and a discrete part. Everything is very explicit.
On the other hand, it is a classical fact that, on a compact Riemannian manifold, the Laplace operator has compact resolvent, hence has discrete spectrum.

Comment: Many thanks! I apologize that I asked the question without any preliminary studying of the subject (I was reading in physical papers about possible presence of continuous spectrum in some cases but have doubts about generality of that).  It looks that the same situation may take place for general case, when $B$ is non-compact but of finite volume and arbitrary $n$. It will be good to have also a standard citation about the classical fact you have mentioned for the compact case.

Comment: @Vladimir: The link provided by Marcel contains a number of useful references. See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace–Beltrami_operator

Comment: The spectrum will never be discrete, due to the presence of Eisenstein series in non-uniform lattices (morally, by the Kazhdan-Margulis theorem - non-uniform lattices implies existence of unipotents...). 

Nevertheless, by the Gelfand-Graev theorem, the cuspidal spectrum is always discrete! (hence the Laplacian is essentially compact).
Randol has shown how to construct quotients of $PSL_{2}$ with arbitrarily small spectral gap, and therefore any meaningful bound towards Ramanujan will involve number-theoretical considerations/constructions

Comment: P.S. due to the Phillips-Sarnak result, it is widely believed that for "typical" B (where typical should be understood properly) there should be only finitely many points in the discrete spectrum.